# Insert JSON data into a field (e.g. first name in contact) into dynamics

Tags: c#, json, dynamics-crm

I have the following JSON data stored in an external database:

```
{
 "id": "emulator:conversation4acee870-4bf7-11e9-849f-abbeb92fb354|livechat",
 "botId": "05682e70-4410-11e9-bd6d-d3b4ec617e06",
 "channelId": "emulator",
 "conversationId": "4acee870-4bf7-11e9-849f-abbeb92fb354|livechat",
 "userId": "72aee04c-8ce5-4c1e-abfe-32680a5f2404",
 "data": {
     "FirstName": "sam",
     "Surname": "smith"
 },
 "etag":"2355667676",
 "attachement":"222445666"
}
```

What I would like to do is to get the values of `firstname` and place it into dynamics new contact entity.

At the moment I have created a console app and have connected to my external database and dynamics 365. The connection from the console app to the dynamics works.
I am able to query the database and retrieve the request values. However, I do not know how to insert the JSON data in dynamics.

```
class Program
{

  public static IOrganizationService axoService;
  public static IOrganizationService service;
  private Guid _accountId;
  public Guid _contactId;
  //connect to cosmos db
  private const string EndpointUrl = "https://botstore.documents.azure.com:###/";
  private const string PrimaryKey = "Z###########################=";
  private DocumentClient client;

  static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      Task.Run(async () =>
      {
          var endpoint = EndpointUrl;
          var masterKey = PrimaryKey;
          using (var client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpoint), masterKey))
          {

              Console.WriteLine(">>>> Querying Document <<<<<<");

              //returns all
              var response = client.CreateDocumentQuery(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("botdb","botcollection"),"select * from c").ToList();

              //returns first one
              var g = response.First();
              Console.WriteLine($"id:{g.id}");

              //return botid contains convo
              var p = response.Where(op => op.id.Contains("conv")).ToList().First();


              Console.WriteLine($"id2:{p.id}");
              Console.WriteLine($"id2:{p.botId}");
              Console.WriteLine($"id2:{p.data.FirstName}");
              Console.WriteLine("Query done");

              //After query delete conversation? maybe after it is added to dynamics, then delete in another function

              var connectionString = @"AuthType = Office365; Url = https://#####.crm11.dynamics.com/;Username=s######@dynamics.co.uk;Password=########";
              CrmServiceClient conn = new CrmServiceClient(connectionString);

              axoService = conn.OrganizationServiceProxy;

              IOrganizationService _orgService;
              orgService = (IOrganizationService)conn.OrganizationWebProxyClient != null ? (IOrganizationService)conn.OrganizationWebProxyClient : (IOrganizationService)conn.OrganizationServiceProxy;

              RetrieveVersionRequest versionRequest = new RetrieveVersionRequest();
              RetrieveVersionResponse versionResponse =(RetrieveVersionResponse)_orgService.Execute(versionRequest);

              Console.WriteLine("Microsoft Dynamics CRM version {0}.",versionResponse.Version);

              var pop = p.data.FirstName;//gets the value from json 
              data//sam

              Entity cont = new Entity("contact");        

              cont["firstname"] = pop;//error:Type **'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' is a recursive collection data contract which is not supported. Consider modifying the definition of collection 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' to remove references to itself.**- this is not WCF though so don't have service references

              cont["lastname"] = "Simmmmmmspsson";

              axoService.Create(cont);

              Console.WriteLine("new contact added");
              Console.ReadLine();
```

How do I insert JSON data in a FirstName field in the contact entity in Microsoft Dynamics?

Comment: Have you try to use the DataContractJsonSerializer to serialize and deserialize your JSON?

Comment: Or use https://www.newtonsoft.com/json to serialize and deserialize your JSON as required.

Comment: since this is json data would i just need to deserialize the Json?

Comment: Yes, you can do that by creating a model for your JSON. I am working on an example to show you.

Comment: See this example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/46O8n4. I am using Newtonsoft JSON package for .NET

Comment: thank you. With regards to the string json variable, is there a way of not hard coding this? as the json data is retrieved from a database

Comment: @Sam, try this => `var pop = p.data.FirstName.ToString();` and let me know :)

Comment: @Sam, the assumption here is that the JSON string will come from your database but will have the model type that I have created. Basically the structure of the JSON should be the same.

Comment: Thank you ! it worked! Appreciate it so much

Comment: @Sam, Can I add above comment code in my answer?

Comment: yes sure you can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote your code as,

```
cont["firstname"] = pop;
```

So in the above line, the `pop` may contain data but its type is `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken` and not a pure string.

But your Contract Entity require pure string,

So that's why It throws an error like,

> Type **'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' is a recursive collection data contract which is not supported. Consider modifying the definition of collection 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' to remove references to itself.

So, if you change the type from `JToken` to `string` then your exception may go away

```
var pop = p.data.FirstName.ToString();
```

OR

```
var pop = Convert.ToString(p.data.FirstName);
```